# Solve BVP $y''-y=t^2$ by green's function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

> Construct the green's function for the following boundary value problem and use it to find the solution of $$y''-y=t^2,\quad y(0)=0,y(1)=0$$

I got the complementary solution as: $$y_c=c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}$$
Following this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/424104/871843), let $y_1=e^t$ and $y_2=e^{-t}$. Then [$$\textrm{Wronskian}=W(y_1,y_2)=-2$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=wronskian+for+%7Be%5Et%2Ce%5E-t%7D)

$$G(t,u)=\frac{y_1(u)y_2(t)-y_1(t)y_2(u)}{W(y_1,y_2)}=\frac{e^ue^{-t}-e^te^{-u}}{-2}$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
y_p&=\int_0^tG(t,u)f(u)\:du\\
&=\int _0^t\:\left(\frac{e^ue^{-t}-e^te^{-u}}{-2}\cdot \:u^2\right)\:du\\
&=e^{-t}\left(-2e^t-t^2e^t+e^{2t}+1\right)
\end{align}
$$

But the solution mentioned in the book was, $$-\frac{\sinh (1-t)}{\sinh 1}\left[t^2\cosh t-2t\sinh t+2\cosh t-2\right]-\frac{\sinh t}{\sinh 1}\left[t^2\cosh(1-t)+2t\sinh (1-t)+2\cosh(1-t)-3\right]$$

Did I do anything wrong when following that answer? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's a typo in how you wrote $G$ originally. Anyway, you could check whether they're the same function written differently or not?

Comment: Here I just use different notation to match everything with my book @lan

Comment: No, you didn't. Because the way you originally wrote $G$ is just zero. It's a simple mistake, though.

Comment: Aha, that a typo. Thanks to mention that @lan